# Mapping same URL to different controllers in spring based on query parameter

Tags: spring, url, mapping

I'm using spring annotation based controller. I want my URL /user/messages to map to some controller a if query parameter tag is present otherwise to some different controller b. This is required because when parameter tag  is present then some more parameters can be present along with that which i want to handle in different controller to keep the implementation clean.Is there any way to do this in spring. Also is there any other elegant solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go the Spring route, you can checkout the HandlerInterceptor mentioned [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). The Interceptor can take a look at your query param and redirect the link to something else that can be caught by another SimpleUrlMapper.

The other way is to send it to a single controller and let the controller forward to another action if the query parameter is "b".

Comment: HandlerInterceptor sounds cool, but for the time being i think i'll take the second approach. I'm little confused how to check for presence or absence of some parameter in spring based controller.Even if i know that some query parameter is present or not, then i'll need to put a check inside controller to take action based on that, so if(tag==someValue) then i'll do x  but in case there is no parameter with the name 'tag' how to handle that ?

Comment: @kcr: Not sure if I understood the question but you can use the HttpServletRequest in your Controller and call getParameterMap which should give you a map of key and value for the current request. You can then query the Map to see if the param is present.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `params` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation to select an controller method depending on Http parameters.

See this example:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createForm() {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView list() {
    ...
}
```

It is a REST style like Spring ROO uses: if the request contains the parameter `forms` then the `createForm` handler is used, if not the `list` method is used.

Comment: sounds good , will try it out later...for the time being i've found an alternate approach with something like @RequestParam(value="tag", required=false) and then checking for null value of 'tag' parameter