# Handling one jsp-page with 2 different Spring controllers

Tags: spring, controllers

Does anybody know if one can map single jsp page to two different controllers in Spring?

For example, I have a page(with a few forms) with a several functionality submit buttons and I want them to be processed by different controllers, so to say 2 different java files, not that one will redirect me to another 2 controllers. 
I have seen this: [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448895/mapping-same-url-to-different-controllers-in-spring-based-on-query-parameter), but dont really understand how should this work :S

thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Nigul! Your question is unclear and I couldn't get how does your *Similar Question* relate to your question. Mapping one JSP to two different controllers *is different from* mapping one URL to two different controllers.

Comment: sorry for ambigious question! im also kinda frustrated. maybe that is the reason. i have one jsp page which fetches database information. now i need to extend it with 1 text form with textfield for searching. but this should be handled with another controller. how can this be done? Thank you for your time!

Comment: OK I think I got you. Please see my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSP name is `my_page.jsp`. You can use it with as many controllers as you like, just make sure that you return address of this JSP through your `ModelAndView` object:

```
return new ModelAndView("/my_page.jsp");
```

Also, don't forget that you might be using some objects within your JSP, which you must pass through ALL of your controllers (which using this JSP), otherwise you might be getting `NullPointerException`s from the JSP:

```
return new ModelAndView("/my_page.jsp")
.addObject("object_1_required_by_jsp", object1RequiredByJSP)
.addObject("object_2_required_by_jsp", object2RequiredByJSP);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not really. i need to process the page with these controllers, no to send the result from them to the page. (

Comment: I have same problem. Did you found solution?

Comment: @svlada, I cant really say i found the solution. But I found the way around. What I did is I created an intermediate page to which I am redirected when i press the button. that page is empty. and i handle it with its own controller (with handleRequest) and from this controller I return ModelAndView to the main page, the one which should be unique in my case. So, basically i have two controllers, however i have now 2 pages. but it works as I needed it. I hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I ended up with one method in a misc controller that dispatches to the different controllers (which are injected) depending on the request param.